# Se multiplican las respuestas del servidor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Tengo un problema con mi código, quiero hacer múltiples peticiones usando un foreach para que se envíe en este caso 7 veces, los datos se envían bien 7 veces, pero la respuesta del servidor son 14 veces, literalmente se duplica, quisiera saber como arreglar este problema, si alguien sabe les agradecería

```
   const enviarDatosServidor = async (datos) => {
      let DatosJson = JSON.stringify(datos)
      console.log(DatosJson);
      const api = axios.create({baseURL : URL.servidor});
      const response = await api.post('/api-php-react/info_docente.php', DatosJson);
      let res = response.data
      console.log(res);
   }

    Datos.forEach(element => {
        const mat = element.id
        const nota = Notas.filter(data=> data.id_materia === mat)
        const notas = nota.map(data => data.id_nota)
        const total = notas.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        const promedio = total / notas.length
        let arregloDatos = {promedio : promedio, materia : mat}
        enviarDatosServidor(arregloDatos)
    });
```

Comment: Hola amigo, por favor podrías compartir también el código de tu servidor?... nos quedamos cortos si sólo nos pasas el código del cliente

Comment: Es que el problema solo es del lado del cliente, puesto a que se envía dos veces

Comment: Primero mira la variable "Datos", no valla a ser que sea 14 en vez de 7, mira cuantas veces se ejecuta el foreach.
Otro podría ser que mires los verbos de respuesta, algunos navegadores primero envían una petición OPTIONS al servidor y después si envían la POST, y en total serían el doble de peticiones.

Comment: Si, deberías poner un console.log dentro del ciclo y realmente validar que se ejecuta solo 7 veces. y sino nos cuentas